# Website notification counter in android using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview, jsoup

I have a webview containing a site.
I would like to extract a int value from the page.
the html code of the part I would convert is:

```html
<body>
   

     <div class="toolbar" id="main-toolbar">
            <a> <!-- something--> </a>
            <a> <!-- something--> </a>
            <a> <!-- something--> </a>
            <a href="https://thesitethatI'mtalkingabout.com/it/me/notifications" data-unread="1" class="toolbar__item cta-login ">
                    <span class="is-icon-bell toolbar__icon"></span>
                    <span class="toolbar__badge">1</span>
                    "
                                   Notifications
                             "
                    </a> 
    <!--this is the notification number, if you aren't logged in this would be empty--> 
        </div>
    </body>
```

now I would extract the value (in this case 1) from the page and make a variable in my app with it. How can I do that?
It would be even better to be able to extract the value from data-unread"1" instead of from the span.

The number I'm looking for is the notification count of a website. For Jsoup to find him, he must be logged in. The webView I'm using allows you to log in. Is there a way for Jsoup to analyze the HTML of the page as it appears in the webview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) parser:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("someurl").get();
        Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
        Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("span");  <--- here you specify the html tag where is the text is located
        String[] temp1 = new String[99];    
        int i =0;
        for(Element element: elementsHtml){
            temp1[i] = element.text();
            i++;
        }
```

You have to just follow the [CSS selector-syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to find elements. Text is parsed as String afcourse. Use Number classes like Integer, Double to parse values in other formats.

To perform log-in operations  you can use other methods from [Connection](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) interface, such as:

- cookie(), cookies​() - to add cookies
- data​() - to get/set data
- execute() - to execute the request
- get() - execute request as GET and parse the result
- header(), headers() - to add request header
- method() - set the request method
- post() - execute request as POST and parse the result
- timeout() - set the request timeout
- url() - set the request URLurl
- userAgent() - set the user-agent

For example, check out this snippet:

```
try {
    //grab login form page first
    Response loginPageResponse = 
    Jsoup.connect("someurl")
    .referrer("http://www.rediff.com/")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
    .timeout(10 * 1000)
    .get();

    System.out.println("Fetched login page");

    //get the cookies from the response
    Map<String, String> mapLoginPageCookies = loginPageResponse.cookies();

    //make data map containing all the parameters and its values found in the form
    Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapParams.put("FormName", "existing");
    mapParams.put("seclogin", "on");
    mapParams.put("login", "YOUR_USER_ID");
    mapParams.put("passwd", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
    mapParams.put("remember", "1");
    mapParams.put("proceed", "Go");

    //URL found in form's action attribute
    String strActionURL = "https://mail.rediff.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi";

    Response responsePostLogin =
    Jsoup.connect("someurl/login")
     .referrer("someurl/login")//referrer will be the login page's URL
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
     .timeout(10 * 1000)
    .data(mapParams)//post parameters                    
    .cookies(mapLoginPageCookies)//cookies received from login page
    .post();

    System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + responsePostLogin.statusCode());

    //parse the document from response
    Document document = responsePostLogin.parse();
    System.out.println(document);

    //get the cookies
    Map<String, String> mapLoggedInCookies = responsePostLogin.cookies();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, I have a misty. The number I'm looking for is the notification count of a website. For Jsoup to find him, he must be logged in. The webView I'm using allows you to log in. Is there a way for Jsoup to analyze the HTML of the page as it appears in the webview?